# How to remove unwanted space between words inside a character vector using R?

Tags: regex, r

I have a character vector like:

```
"I t is tim e to g o"
```

I wanted it to be:

```
"It is time to go"
```

Comment: Can you give us your code so far ?

Comment: The closest I can get you is `gsub("([A-Za-z])\\s(?=[A-Za-z]\\b)", "\\1", "I t is tim e to g o", perl = TRUE)`, though I can't seem to separate the last two words

Comment: What algorithm do you propose to distinguish wanted from unwanted space?

Comment: how do you handle `A q uestion needs a n a nswer` `A q uestion need s a g ood a nswer`?

Comment: [@DavidArenburg I'm a beginner learner of R. The only codes i know to remove unwanted space are gsub("(^ | $)","", text1, perl=T) & gsub(" {2,}", " ", text, perl=T)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27400286/how-to-remove-unwanted-space-between-words-inside-a-character-vector-using-r)

Comment: You can't.  How do you expect **any** software language to know what constitutes a word and what doesn't?  Do we really need to post links to infamous "spell checker" disasters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [rex](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rex/index.html) may make this type of task a little simpler.  Although in this case maybe not :)

```
string <- "I t is tim e to g o"

library(rex)
re_substitutes(string, rex(
    space %if_next_is%
      list(
        list(non_space, space, at_least(non_space, 2)) %or%
        list(non_space, end)
      )
    ), "", global = TRUE)

#> [1] "It is time to go"
```

Comment: [Thank you very much](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27400286/how-to-remove-unwanted-space-between-words-inside-a-character-vector-using-r/27452498#27452498)

Answer (score 2):

This regex works in your case: `"\\s(?=\\S\\s\\S{2,}|\\S$)"`

```
string <- "I t is tim e to g o"
gsub("\\s(?=\\S\\s\\S{2,}|\\S$)", "", string, perl=TRUE)

## [1] "It is time to go"
```

Try this.Replace by `empty string`.
See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/nL5yL3/32

Comment: [Thank you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27400286/how-to-remove-unwanted-space-between-words-inside-a-character-vector-using-r)

Comment: [Sorry @vks, actually it is not working because i received error message: Error: '\ S' is an unrecognized escape code in a string starting characters "" (= \ S? " I wanted to try to solve the question by using ur code. But it seems like i'm failed to do it. I'm sorry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27400286/how-to-remove-unwanted-space-between-words-inside-a-character-vector-using-r/27401349?noredirect=1#comment43248001_27401349)

Comment: [Actually, I need to use gsub or grep? I'm a very very beginner learner](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27400286/how-to-remove-unwanted-space-between-words-inside-a-character-vector-using-r/27401349?noredirect=1#comment43248203_27401349)

Comment: [Like this: v <- grep("\\S(?=\S\s\S{2,}|\S$, perl=T)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27400286/how-to-remove-unwanted-space-between-words-inside-a-character-vector-using-r/27401349?noredirect=1#comment43248628_27401349)

Comment: @Kitty yes something like this